# VSTO Excel 2007 c# how to select Ribbon TAB?

Tags: c#, vba, vsto

**UPDATE**: okey seems it's all about using **Office PIA 2007** and **Office PIA 2010**. **How to migrate to PIA 2010 for users who have Office 2007 office**? I removed 2007 PIA and added 2010, checked on few clients Office 2013+ versions it's working. But on Office 2007 add-in doesn't load same as on my dev computer. But I'm receiving 0 errors on VS and can see iRibbonUI -> ActivateTab. On computer with office 2007 tried to install PIA 2010 but that doesn't helped.

**Problem**:

I'm using **Visual Studio 2010**, **.NET 3.5** and **Office 2007**, can't find way to select my own created tabs maybe it's related to office version installed?

In VBA Excel library lists if i select "**Office**" -> "**iRibbonUI**" i get only "**Invalidate**" and "**InvalidateControl**", i checked this on **Office365** - i get a lot more "**ActivateTab**" "**ActitaveTabMso**" and so on. In VS when I try to use "**ActiveTab**" i get error "**Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonUI**" does not contain definition for "**ActiveTab**".

Maybe I'm missing something? I can't change to higher office due i need soft be able run on **Office 2007+**.

Any replies appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have tried but you could choose a tab as follows:

```
Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.RibbonUI.ActivateTab("yourtabname")
```

If you find this useful and want more tips and how-to's, you could also register for my course on [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/excel-vsto-add-ins/)

Comment: As I wrote there is no such definition. And it seems its due I have office 2007 + PIA 2007. I need to soemhow change project for PIA 2010 and fix clients version too.